# When Upgrade Laravel 5.8 to 6.0 - laravel/framework v6.0.4 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.8) does not satisfy that requirement

Tags: laravel

I currently have a Laravel application running Laravel version 5.8. I want to upgrade to 6.0.  In composer.json I change

`"laravel/framework": "5.8.*",`   to `"laravel/framework": "6.0.*",`

and then run composer update I get the following error

```
- laravel/framework v6.0.4 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

I have also ran composer install then composer update and get same error. How would I update my PHP version?

My question was closed for lacking more details. I am not sure what other details to give. When I open mamp -> preferences -> PHP, this shows Standard Version 7.3.7. Yet when I run php -v from the command line, this shows PHP 7.1.8. If I run PHP Info from Mamp, this shows PHP 7.3.7.
 Is my machine running more than one version of PHP? I have search on how to upgrade PHP and not finding correct answers. Any help appreciated?

Comment: What OS are you running using?

Comment: I am running windows

Comment: If you ran `php --version` and it's returning `7.1.8`, then you need to upgrade PHP to 7.2... The message it's giving you is pretty clear. A simple Google search for "Upgrade PHP version" should help you solve this issue. What have you tried? What specific issue are you facing?

Comment: Also, follow the instructions on https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade; there's more to the upgrade that just upgrading PHP version.

Comment: You just need to update your php version to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You got this error from your `composer`, which is a dependency Manager for PHP. On your system you have installed php version `7.1.8`, but `Laravel 6.0.4` requires php version `7.2` or higher.

You can check your current php version from Terminal or cmd like this

```
$ php --version
```

Comment: Yes have ran php --version. returns PHP 7.1.8

Comment: @DukesNuz, yes, update your system's php version :)

Comment: Thank you for all the help. Problem solved. I wrote a [blog post](https://david.dukesnuz.com/blog/24/Website%20Development/how-to-update-php-version-and-change-php-folder-which-composer-a-php-dependency-manager-is-using) on my solution.

Comment: @DukesNuz don't forget to validate my answer in case your problem is solved by it